# Read/write appointment RTF from Exchange Server 2007

Tags: c#, rtf, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007

What im tryng to do is

- get appointment
- modify it externally
- write updates to exchange

When im doing it with Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService i will suck at the fist point, because im getting some weird rendered html without actual layout data.

So my only thought is to do it via RTF. But ExchangeService supports only text and html.

Is it possible to read/write appointment RTF from exchange server any other way?

Answer (score 0):

With "Exchange Web Services .NET" (Independentsoft) is possible to read/write RTF body using MapiProperty.PR_RTF_COMPRESSED field. Same should be possible with Microsoft API.